# OAuth 2.0/ OpenIdConnect Prompt = "login" allows a whole new user to sign in

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I just wanted to get some clarification around this. I'm an Oauth2 rookie, and I'm currently implementing Prompt = "login" into my app which should allow me to enforce re-authentication of the user wherever I choose within my app.

One thing that has me a bit dismayed though is that it doesn't seem like Oauth2 or openidconnect has any specifications for validating that the same user re-authenticated.

For example, say joe@test.com originally signed in and is authenticated into my app. Joe now wants to perform an intimate action within my app but I want him to re-authenticate first. During re-authentication he signs in as Suzy@test.com. There doesn't seem to be an explicit way of enforcing that the new user match the previously authenticated user.

I would love any insight on this snippet.

Thanks all who view!

Ruben

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything built into the framework to handle this. So I ended up persisting the username at the time of issuing the Challenge by adding it to the OIDC State field. I then compare the initial username that's stored in the state with the username that is returned the external IDP provider. If they do not match, I reject the auth request.